# Scrapy callback function in another file

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy with Python to scrape several websites.

I got many Spiders with a structure like this:

```
import library as lib

class Spider(Spider):
   ...

   def parse(self, response):
       yield FormRequest(..., callback=lib.parse_after_filtering_results1)
       yield FormRequest(..., callback=lib.parse_after_filtering_results2)

   def parse_after_filtering_results1(self,response):
       return results

   def parse_after_filtering_results2(self,response):
       ... (doesn't return anything)
```

I would like to know if there's any way I can put the last 2 functions, which are called in the callback, in another module that is common to all my Spiders (so that if I modify it then all of them change). I know they are class functions but is there anyway I could put them in another file?

I have tried declaring the functions in my library.py file but my problem is how can I pass the 2 parameters needed (self, response) to them.

Comment: Yes, just make sure to import them correctly (which seems like what you already tried to do, otherwise I don't understand the `lib.`)

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, I am importing them, my problem is how can I pass arguments to them? Because the callback function doesn't allow me to do it (it needs to be callable indeed :) )

Comment: Could you just call the object instance directly in lieu of `self`? Im not exactly sure whats the issue here, perhaps you could construct a more practical example and I would be able to help better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a base class to contain those common functions. Then your real spiders can inherit from that. For example, if all your spiders extend `Spider` then you can do the following:

`spiders/basespider.py:`

```
from scrapy import Spider

class BaseSpider(Spider):
    # Do not give it a name so that it does not show up in the spiders list.
    # This contains only common functions.

    def parse_after_filtering_results1(self, response):
        # ...

    def parse_after_filtering_results2(self, response):
        # ...
```

`spiders/realspider.py:`

```
from .basespider import BaseSpider

class RealSpider(BaseSpider):
     # ...

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest(..., callback=self.parse_after_filtering_results1)
        yield FormRequest(..., callback=self.parse_after_filtering_results2)
```

If you have different types of spiders you can create different base classes. Or your base class can be a plain object (not `Spider`) and then you can use it as a mixin.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! One question, if you don't include a "name" attribute in a Spider Class then that spider doesn't appear when you type "scrapy list" command in the terminal? Just curious why the "scrapy list" command does not include the BaseSpider.

Comment: @JorgeGarcia Yes, that is the reason. I updated the answer to include that. It also prevents it from showing up as a spider if you use the ScrapingHub service.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! :)